# How to install and use python module on Win 64?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

Trying to make use of this package: https://github.com/microsoft/Simplify-Docx

Can someone pls tell me the proper sequence of actions needed to install and use the package?

What I've tried (as a separate commands from vscode terminal):

```
pip install python-docx
Git clone <git link>
python setup.py install
```

After the installation has been successfully completed I'm trying to run from VS Code terminal the file in which I've pasted the code from readme's "usage" section:

```
import docx
from simplify_docx import simplify

# read in a document 
my_doc = docx.Document("docxinaprojectfolder.docx") //I wonder how should I properly specify the path to file?

# coerce to JSON using the standard options
my_doc_as_json = simplify(my_doc)

# or with non-standard options
my_doc_as_json = simplify(my_doc,{"remove-leading-white-space":False})
```

And I only get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'
```

But I've installed this module in the first place. 
What am I doing wrong? Am I missing some of the steps? (Like init or smth).

Vscode status bar at the bottom left says that I'm using python 3.8.x, and I'm trying to run the script via "play" button.

```
python --version
Python 3.6.5

py show's though that 3.8.x is being used.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your system doesn't have "docx" module.

to install docx module you will have to install docx.

steps to install:
1) open CMD prompt.
2) type "pip install docx"

if your installation is fresh it may need "simplify" module too.

Comment: C:\concert2\Simplify-Docx>pip install docx
Requirement already satisfied: docx in c:\users\1\appdata\local\programs\python\
python36-32\lib\site-packages

I think it might be versions issue, I've installed, but when running it keeps saying: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'
How do I force the proper version of python to be used?

Comment: Okay, so the problem is different environments.
Kindly follow these steps
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-05-installing-packages?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1):

Amin sama was right - that was indeed an environment issue. 
Looks like modules were getting globally installed in an older python folder. Different from the python which runs when you try to run python file. So I had to uninstall the older python.

After that

```
py --version
```

and

```
Python --version
```

Started to show the same version unlike before.

So, the sequence
 1. Opened a fresh folder within VS Code
 2. `git clone <git link to repository from github>`
 3. copied all the files from cloned repo to my current folder (or you can go one level down with cd command)
 4. installed dependency: `pip install python-docx`
 5. run setup.py from where you copied files: `python setup.py install`
 6. Copy "usage" into a new file, for example run.py
 7. Specify an absolute path to your file with double backslash.
 8. Add strings to run.py to output the result in a json:

```
import json
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(my_doc_as_json, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

9. Run this file from the terminal opened in your project folder typing `run.py` or `python run.py`

It wasn't necessary to open `>>>` python console.

Answer (score 0):

Like any python package that doesn't come with python, you need to install it before using it. In your terminal window you can install if from the Python package index like this:

```bash
pip install simplify-docx
```

or you can install it directly from GitHub like this:

```bash
pip install git+git://github.com/microsoft/Simplify-Docx.git
```